# Sharepoint ClientContext

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I want to ask regarding sharepoint clientClient context:

```
var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('splist');
```

It returns the current web url (https://sharepoint.com/sites/site1). However i want to get the url of other tenant URL which is (https://sharepoint.com/sites/site2).

Tried googling this but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You can open a new ClientContex to a different site than the one you are one with the below way:

```
let clientContext = new SP.ClientContext("https://sharepoint.com/sites/site2");
let oList = clientContext
      .get_web()
      .get_lists()
      .getByTitle("Test List");
```

The above code is the initialization part of the ClientContext Object.

What you have to be aware of is that since you open a context with the perspective of the user and, afterwards, perfoms some kind of action, you have to make sure that the use has a High-enough Access Level in order to perform the action.

For the next, step you can use the ClientContext Object in order to get List Items from a list and define some callbacks in order to handle Query retrieval succes or any exceptions that might occur.

```
query.set_viewXml("<View>.... some CAML query ....</View>");
items = oList.getItems(query);
clientContext.load(items);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);
```